# Kotlin Annotation Processing: is it possible to generate an extension method?

Tags: annotations, kotlin

I'm playing around with Kotlin and I think that it would be great to have "*functional classes*", see the example of what I want:

```scala
functional class MyStrFunction(val function: MyStrFunction.(String) -> String) {
    val memory = HashMap<String, String>()
    fun output(message: String) = println(message)
}
```

The idea is that I would be able to use it like:

```scala
val f = MyStrFunction { 
    output("reversing $it"); 
    if (it in memory)
        output(memory[it])
    return it.reverse() 
}
```

If I were to write `MyStrFunction` which I want by myself, the resulting class would be:

```scala
class MyStrFunction(val function: MyStrFunction.(String) -> String) {
    val memory = HashMap<String, String>()
    fun output(message: String) = println(message)

    public fun invoke(s: String) = this.function(s)
}
```

But it's tedious a bit to write this by hands in every "*functional class*".

So here's my question: is it possible to make `functional` an annotation and then process it adding `invoke` method with the desired code?

I know that **kapt** can be used for Kotlin annotation processing, but AFAIK for now it cannot generate Kotlin code and there's no way to make an extension function in Java generated code.

Is there any way to generate a new Kotlin method for a class?

*Node: I understand that the idea of functional classes has few use cases and that it's not that hard to add the mentioned `invoke` method manually, but for me it's academical interest to the concept of annotation processing in Kotlin.*

UPD: Just my thought about functional classes: there's language feature of delegating interfaces and it would work good here, but `this` reference is not visible in that block. Example:

```scala
class MyStrFunction(val function: MyStrFunction.(String) -> String)
: (String) -> String by { this.function(it) } { // <-- won't compile :(
    val memory = HashMap<String, String>()
    fun output(message: String) = println(message)
}
```

Comment: You can search or add an issue to [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com) asking for the feature of KAPT to generate Kotlin.   This way you will be able to track progress for the feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure, if what you want can be done directly, however here's an approach without "functional classes". As far as I understand you want to add functionality to a regular lambda function. First, define your *functionality* as a regular class:

```
class Memory() {
    val memory = hashMapOf<String, String>()
    fun output(message: String) = println(message)
}
```

Then define a helper function to bind extension functions to a receiver:

```
fun <T, R, E> T.bind(function: T.(R) -> E): (R) -> E = { this.function(it) }
```

And then use it like this

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val mem = Memory()

    val memoryFunction: Memory.(String) -> String = {
        output("reversing $it");
        if (it in memory)
            output(memory[it])
        it.reverse()
    }

    val function: (String) -> String = mem.bind(memoryFunction)

    println(listOf("foo", "bar").map(function))
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the approach that you suggest looks good for this case.
But I'd still like to do the same without redundant and duplicated code at the class usage and, if possible, even without additional code in the class.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you can keep the original class exactly like you declared (but without the `functional`):

```
class MyStrFunction(val function: MyStrFunction.(String) -> String) {
    val memory = HashMap<String, String>()
    fun output(message: String) = println(message)
}
```

And to use it just add a `.function` at the end

```
val f = MyStrFunction {
    output("reversing $it")
    if (it in memory) output(memory[it] ?: "")

    it.reversed()
}.function
```